# select all substrings where we can select non-empty and all characters are identical

Tags: python

given a string S, return an integer that represents number of ways which we can select non-empty substrings of S where all characters of substrings are identical.

Eg. "zzzyz" should return 7

4 instances of "z"
1 instance of "zz"
1 instance of "zzz"
1 instance of "y"

I'm thinking iterating through all the possible combinations and only returning those with all() = to True

```
def solution(string):
   lst = []
   for i in string:
       for ii in string[1:]:
           lst.append((i,ii))

   return len([i for i in lst if all(i)])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask homework questions, you should give some context, or some code. This way we can help you. We aren't here to do your homework, rather to help you along the way if you need it. Thanks!

Comment: first see what you have in `lst` - it is not what you expect. Second; `all()` doesn't works as you expect - `print(all(['z', 'y']))` gives `True`. Better use `len( set(some_list) )` if all elements are the same then length will be `1`, if elements are different then length will be bigger then `1`

Comment: BTW: there are 2 instances of `zz` and result is `8`

Answer (score 2):

You should use external `for`-loop to get length of substrings - 1, 2, 3, ... - and internal `for`-loop to create all substrings with this lenght.

`all()` doesn't work as you expect. It doesn't check if elements are the same but if all elements gives `True` for `bool(element)` - and all not-empty strings gives `True`

You can use `set()` to check if all elements are the same - for the same elements `set()` will have length `1`

```
def solution(string):
    lst = []

    for length in range(1, len(string)+1):
        #print('length:', length)
        for x in range(0, len(string)-length+1):
            substring = string[x:x+length]
            #print(substring, len(set(substring)))
            if len(set(substring)) == 1:
                lst.append(substring)

    return len(lst)

print(solution('zzzyz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

So yes this was an interview question , I didn't get it the first time but the second time I took it here's what I got:

```
# input string 
S = "zzzyz"

# We want to emulate this logic
# loop 1    loop2
# z         (zzyz)
# z         (zyz)
# z         (yz)
# y         (z)
# z         ()


equal_substrings = 0

# iterate through all chars
for n, s in enumerate(S):
     # each char gets += 1
     equal_substrings += 1
     # 2nd loop: iterate through remaining chars
     for ss in S[n+1:]:
          # if this char = last char, += 1
          # else break
          if ss == s:
               equal_substrings += 1
          else:
               break
```

Answer (score 0):

A linear time solution.

```
string = "zzzyz"


def sumNum(n):
    return (n * (n + 1)) // 2


def function(string):
    prev = string[0]
    count = 1
    output = 0
    for char in string[1:]:
        if char == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            prev = char
            print(f"count - {count}")
            output += sumNum(count)
            count = 1
    print(f"count - {count}")
    output += sumNum(count)
    print(output)
```